# SPAlert Created, But Not Sending Email

Tags: sharepoint-server, alert

I have a SharePoint webpart that creates an alert for a user, for a specific list item (in this case, a document set).  I am adding the alert programmatically.  The code executes without any errors, and I can see the alert when I click "Manage My Alerts" in SharePoint.  The event type is "All", so alerts should get sent when someone adds a document to the document set.  However, after the alert is created, and I add a document to the document set for which the alert was created, no email gets sent.  I double-checked the email address and other settings for the alert, and everything looks OK.  Additionally, I found the following entry in the event log:

> Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly 'ListItemEventHandler, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71a9581283b81d5f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This entry was added five times.  I assume this is related to the alert that was added. Does anyone know why the email notifications don't get sent?

PS: If I add the alert using "Alert Me" in SharePoint, the emails get sent.

Comment: Do you have any event receivers associated with the library?

Comment: No, I don't have any event receivers associated with the library.

Comment: Do event receivers have to be associated with the library?  None of the examples I read regarding programmatically adding events mention event receivers.

Comment: We can have event receivers attached to list/libraries. And it enables us to handle `ItemAdding`, `ItemAdded`, etc. events.

Comment: I know what an event receiver is, but is it required in order to get the alert working?  I just added it to my SharePoint solution, re-deployed it and re-ran the code that creates an alert, but I still do not receive email notifications.

Comment: No. I was asking about Event Receivers because of the Error Message you posted as part of the answer. You can check the SMTP server logs as well as SharePoint logs to find what is blocking these emails.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand.  Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the SharePoint logs, and I don't have access to the SMTP server.  I'll just have to keep digging....

Comment: Also, I just found out that the ListItemEventHandler isn't related to this issue.  It's been going on for a while, before I started creating alerts.